# How to set footnotes to use a combination of two numbering formats in ConTeXt?

Tags: numbering, footnotes, context

How can I redefine the numbering style of footnotes in ConTeXt, such that is displays a combination of a number and letter (e.g. `1.A`, `1.B`, `1.C`) instead of the usual 1, 2, 3 sequence, e.g.:

```
This is some text.^1.A This is some more text.^1.B

This is yet some more text.^2.A This is the last text.^2.B
```

- The number needs to only be incremented when done so manually, e.g. with something like `\incrementnumber[footnote]`.
- The letter needs to be incremented each time a new footnote is defined, and reset whenever the number is incremented, e.g. `1.A`, `1.B`, `1.C`, `2.A`, `2.B`, `2.C`.

I have managed to create a partial solution:

```
\definenumber[prefixcounter]
\setnumber[prefixcounter]{1}
\def\footnoteprefix#1{\getnumber[prefixcounter].#1}
\setupnote[footnote][left=\footnoteprefix, numberconversion=set 2]
\starttext
    This is some text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
    This is some more text.\footnote{This is another footnote.}
    \incrementnumber[prefixcounter]
    This is yet some more text.\footnote{This is yet another footnote.}
    This is the last text.\footnote{This is the last footnote.}
\stoptext
```

This solution has several problems:

- `left=\footnoteprefix` is only appearing near the footnote, not in the document text as well.
- `numberconversion` seems to have a limited number of options, such as `set 1`, `set 2`, I could not find any way to set this to use `A`, `B`, `C`, etc., such as is available for [enumerated lists](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Enumerations) according to the ConTeXt wiki.

How can footnotes be created which use this number-letter format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\subfootnote` feature for this. Here is a small example:

```
\setuplayout [height=15cm] % for a smaller screenshot

\definestructureconversionset [footnote] [numbers, Characters] [numbers]
\setupenumerations            [footnote] [numberconversionset=footnote]

\starttext

\startlines
Footnote\footnote{Lorem}
Footnote\footnote{Ipsum}
Subfootnote\subfootnote{Foo}, Subfootnote\subfootnote{Bar}\par

\incrementnumber [footnote]

Footnote\footnote{Dolor}
Footnote\footnote{Sit}
Subfootnote\subfootnote{Foo}, Subfootnote\subfootnote{Bar}\par
\stoplines

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

You need to define a new `structureconversionset` to get the alphabetical numbering. The third argument of `\definestructureconversionset` is the scheme that is used as a default. Unfortunately there's not much documentation available about conversionsets (and the interface has changed in MkIV). Some info is available on the [wiki - setupreferencestructureprefix](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupreferencestructureprefix)

Defining a new `numberseparatorset` is not necessary, since the default one already contains a dot.

Tested with context version: 2011.05.18 18:04, the betas upto November 2011 should work fine, as well. The betas from this year are a nightmare when it comes to footnotes.

Comment: Is there any `\subfootnote` equivalent to `\note` and `\footnotetext`?

Comment: Use `\donote[subfootnote][foo]{*}` as `\note` and `\setnotetext[subfootnote][foo]{bar}` as `\footnotetext`.