# What is the correct syntax for subfootnote?

Tags: footnotes, context, context-mkiv

After upgrading from ConTeXt stable to beta, any code containing `subfootnote` does not compile. E.g.:

```
\definestructureconversionset [footnote] [numbers, Characters] [numbers]
\setupenumerations            [footnote] [numberconversionset=footnote]
\starttext
    \startlines
        This is some text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
        This is some more text.\subfootnote{This is a subfootnote.}
    \stoplines
\stoptext
```

This code, adapted from [How to set footnotes to use a combination of two numbering formats in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51291/how-to-set-footnotes-to-use-a-combination-of-two-numbering-formats-in-context), fails to compile and returns an error on line 6, or essentially any line where `\subfootnote` is placed with the message "Missing number, treated as zero."

Similarly, `\donote[subfootnote][]{}` and `\setnotetext[subfootnote][]{}`, commands needed when placing subfootnotes inside mathmode environments, have problems compiling after this update.

- Has the syntax of `\subfootnote` been changed or entirely removed from ConTeXt beta? Is there a new way to typeset subfootnotes?
- Does the error "Missing number, treated as zero." indicate that I need to add a number somewhere to `\subfootnote`?

Comment: It looks like this changed in the release 2011.05.18.  The [release notes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Release_Notes) which includes a remark about "rewritten mark (header, footer etc. related) code".  [This question](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20120320.074738.3713a4d5.en.html) might be of some help.

Comment: I have tried changing the preamble to use `\setupnotation[footnote][numberconversionset=footnote]`, however, the error about a missing number still appears for every line containing `\subfootnote{}`.

Comment: Since this question has not been answered here for a while, the best option is to ask it on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Comment: Congratulation, [you are the winner!](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors)

Comment: @Village What, as exactly as possible, do you mean by “recently”? From the [commit log](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/history/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/strc-not.mkvi) I guess the bug was introduced when the [note mechanism underwent the update from mkiv to mkvi](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/commitdiff/7b47df8cbaae8690f14d306c633b2b2db053f66a) earlier this year. This is when the code was changed that now fails. Unfortunately I cannot test this as the older versions of the format don’t build anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax did not change. It is a bug and has been fixed in beta 2012.10.15 19:10 (see
[dev-context
subfootnotes](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context.devel/2099)). An
update should be enough to get subfootnotes working again.

However, you can use the MkIV syntax `\startsubfootnote`. So instead of

```
This is some text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
This is some more text.\subfootnote{This is a subfootnote.}
```

you can write

```
This is some text.\startfootnote This is a footnote. \stopfootnote
This is some more text.\startsubfootnote This is a subfootnote. \stopsubfootnote
```

But this just as a side note, it is unrelated to the problem.

The syntax for the subfootnote numbering has changed. Instead of

```
\setupenumerations [footnote] [numberconversionset=footnote]
```

the new syntax is (more information on the [Wiki - Footnotes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Footnotes))

```
\setupnotation [footnote] [numberconversionset=footnote]
```

and `\definestructureconversionset` changed to `\defineconversionset`

Here your full minimal example:

```
\defineconversionset [footnote] [numbers, Characters] [numbers]
\setupnotation       [footnote] [numberconversionset=footnote]

\starttext
  \startlines
      This is some text.\startfootnote This is a footnote. \stopfootnote
      This is some more text.\startsubfootnote This is a subfootnote. \stopsubfootnote
  \stoplines
\stoptext
```

[image: result]